# CSS Dynamic Navigation with Hover - How Do I make it work in iOS Safari?

Tags: javascript, css, safari, ios

In my site I use a CSS only dynamic menu. This is fine in desktop browsers, but not on iOS (iphone, ipad, etc) because the touch interface does not support the `:hover` selector.

My question is: what is the best way of supporting this on iOS? (Ideally either by patching with some CSS, or Javascript that will make the existing code work, rather than doing the whole thing over just to support iOS)

My html looks like this

```
<ul id="nav"> 
  <li> 
     Item 1
     <ul> 
       <li><a href=''>sub nav 1.1</a></li>
       <li><a href=''>sub nav 1.2</a></li>
     </ul> 
  </li> 
  <li> 
     Item 2
     <ul> 
       <li><a href=''>sub nav 2.1</a></li>
       <li><a href=''>sub nav 2.2</a></li>
     </ul> 
  </li> 
  <li> 
     Item 3 
     <ul> 
        <li><a href=''>sub nav 3.1</a></li>
        <li><a href=''>sub nav 3.2</a></li>
    </ul> 
  </li> 
</ul> ​​​​​
```

And the CSS is this

```
#nav li {
    float:left;
    padding:0 15px;
}

#nav li ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10em;
    left: -999em;
    margin-left: -10px;
}

#nav li:hover ul {
    left: auto;
}
```

I have done a jsfiddle of this here: http://jsfiddle.net/NuTz4/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check this article, perhaps it's a solution for you ;)

http://www.usabilitypost.com/2010/05/12/css-hover-controls-on-iphone/

Also JS solution, taken from: http://www.evotech.net/blog/2008/12/hover-pseudoclass-for-the-iphone/

```
var nav = document.getElementById('nav');
var els= nav.getElementsByTagName('li');
for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i++){
    els[i].addEventListener('touchstart', function(){this.className = "hover";}, false);
    els[i].addEventListener('touchend', function(){this.className = "";}, false);
}
```

In jQuery:

```
$('#nav li').bind('touchstart', function(){
    $(this).addClass('hover');
}).bind('touchend', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

css:

```
li:hover, li.hover { /* whatever your hover effect is */ }
```

Comment: I used your jQuery solution but I bound toggleClass() to touchstart so each time the user touches the hover-able element it shows. Touch again to hide.
`$("#nav li").bind("touchstart", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("hover");
});`

Comment: @Colin I believe using "click" instead of "touch..." achieves the same result. My solution is for touch-hovers, but your solution is what most people actually want when you need to interact with the hovered item.

Comment: How would this be done without the use of jQuery? That is if it is possible without it.

Comment: @casillic There are actually 3 solutions here, first one is vanilla javascript, 2nd one is jquery, 3rd one is pure css...