# CSS buttons for touch devices?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a site and have lots of buttons, problem is, if i only add the .active state to the button, nothing shows on the button, and if i add a hover state, then at least one button shows a pressed state when loading the site, and if i click on another button it will always be in hover state. Is there a way around this?

Best

Comment: Would you mind creating an example, on jsfiddle perhaps?  I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this on a touch device by binding the `touchstart` / `touchend` events using javascript.. Check out [BGerrissen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3501615/1029952)

Comment: Pierre, that's exactly what i wanted. merci